# can't install gensim on apple M1

Tags: python, numpy, gensim, apple-m1

I am trying to install python gensim module but getting errors.

```
 Running from numpy source directory.
      /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/core/src/multiarray/buffer.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/buffer.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.14.6-arm64-3.8/numpy/core/src/multiarray/buffer.o.d -faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers" failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
```

```
  distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/var/folders/5d/9599hjpx0tsbp22mcpdsqdc80000gn/T/tmp56vlhe_y', '--quiet', 'numpy>=1.11.3']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am not sure why its building numpy

I installed numpy separately using the conda miniforge as mentioned here: https://towardsdatascience.com/new-apple-silicon-m1-macbook-air-the-dream-laptop-for-machine-learning-engineers-a1590fbd170f

Can someone help if they have more experience with this?

Comment: So did it work when installed via `conda`, or is that the attempt that failed? (It would help to expand your question with the exact commands you ran to trigger the error.) Also, are there any other logs/log-lines relating to the specific `clang` command error you've shown?

Comment: it worked by running the terminal on mac using rosetta.

Comment: Without the exact commands that either succeeded or failed, it's hard to help.(It's hard to even tell if you're still having a problem of if your latest attempt worked so this is no longer a pressing question.)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by running the terminal on mac using rosetta so no longer having this issue. Thanks for replying.