# Install Gensim on the new M1 chip Mac

Tags: python, macos, scipy, gensim, apple-m1

Any leads on how can I install gensim on the M1 chip on the new Mac community?
There hasn't been much news yet for this.
This is the only other question there -

[can't install gensim on apple M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65769069/cant-install-gensim-on-apple-m1)

(and I am not looking to use rosetta)

**ERROR**:

> RuntimeError: Cython extensions are unavailable. Without them, this
> gensim functionality is disabled. If you've installed from a package,
> ask the package maintainer to include Cython extensions.

Comment: A simple pip install (in a Miniconda env) works perfectly fine on my M1 Mac Mini (not using Rosetta). Where exactly do you struggle?

Comment: Do you net get the Cython runtime error? Updated question with the error message. Gesim  installs but I can't use it because of this error.

Comment: How did you try to install Gensim, into what kind of environment? Did you watch the output of the install command for anything anomalous? (Have you tried using a miniconda environment, then installing via `pip` into that environment, as @petezurich reports above works for him?)

Comment: I don't get any errors and can use gensim just fine.

Comment: @gojomo - Installed Miniforge as that is the recommended way to do it on the m1 Mac for now. created a virtual environment using Conda. Now Miniforge library for m1 doesn't have gensim  yet. So I did pip install gensim inside my venv. Now when I run my file, I get the above error.

Comment: Thats great @petezurich. Please let me know how did you install it. Requesting you to give me all the necessary steps.

Comment: There seems not much to add. I install the ARM version of miniconda, make an env (Python v. 3.8) and simply pip install gensim. I can use gensim in notebooks just fine. I don't get any errors whatsoever. Are you sure that you use the M1/ARM version of miniconda? You might want to check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534042/anaconda-and-upgrading-to-new-m1-mac) too.

Comment: where did you install the arm miniconda from? May I kindly have a link?

Comment: I'm not sure where miniforge is the 'recommended' way to do it, but the testimony here is that plain 'miniconda' works, so I'd try that, & not improvise other things. I'd get miniconda from here: https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

Comment: Thanks everyone. Turns out MiniForge was the issue. I uninstalled and installed Miniconda.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I know this is not the best and safest choice, but this thing worked for me. As I wanted to install sklearn on M1, I needed to have anaconda installed, and also the specific channel that supports it was conda-forge. To install Gensim, I just did a simple `pip install gensim` inside of the conda environment where I have my other packages installed.

In general, it's not the best idea to install different packages using a combination of conda and pip, but sadly, I think you have no other choice if you want to make things work on m1.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be applicable to all the cases, but you might want to try this simple test first before trying other more complicated methods (which takes less than 2 mins):

```bash
pip uninstall gensim
pip install gensim
```

What this does in my case is that it uninstall an earlier version of Gensim, and reinstall a later version, which is compatible to my mac. Again, this might not work in your case but there is no harm in trying.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried many things after installing Cython, but none of them worked. Then, I realized that my environment didnt have Numpy and Scipy installed. It is required to have them installed before installing gensim.

> [This software depends on NumPy and Scipy, two Python packages for scientific computing. You must have them installed prior to installing gensim](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim)